# Node Express.js 4 Route Not working, Getting 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webstorm

I've been trying to debug my route in my express app.  The request is undefined but not sure why.

I'm using [Express 4.0](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html) but running it Express 3.0 style (no bin/www).

[image]
[image]
[image]

**server.js**

```
    var app = require('./app')

    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.set('port', port);

app.listen(app.get('port', function(){
    console.log('Express web server is listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
}));
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    routes = require('./routes/index'),
    app = express();

app.use('/', routes);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

module.exports = app;
```

routes/**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I run debug on my app in webstorm, the page throws a 404 page not found.  When I looked at the debug, here's the problem, the http request is undefined:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: App.router has been deprecated, that's why it doesn't work: https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#approuter

Comment: wait I don't see that, are you referring to var router = express.Router(); in my code?  I don't think I even have what you're talking about in my code...

Comment: You have missing parenthesis after app.listen(app.get('port'   so the following function is a callback of app.get but it should be callback of app.listen

Comment: @Molda, thanks weird, wonder why Webstorm didn't warn me of the missing ')'.  Fixed that but still the same state with the error 404 with my route...

Comment: I mean I think the order of my middleware is correct is it not?  Maybe it's trying to route before the app is actually listening hence my request is null

Comment: Just tried your code and it works just fine. Can you try to run it in terminal with simple "node server" ?

Comment: Just tried it with your original server.js with the missing parenthesis and got the same error as you, so it seems the parenthesis is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your app.listen... looks as follows

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express web server is listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```